# sqlite db with less records consumes more space than another db with more records(same structure)

Tags: database, sqlite, relational-database

I have a strange issue here i have 2 sqlite db files

- dev.db - 2 tables - 2000 records - 19.4 mb
- stage.db - 2 tables(same structure and columns as above) - 17441 records - 3.2 mb

cannot understand why db number 1 has less records and consumes more space when compared to the other on.Watching the db structure in db browser tool.

Comment: Are both table structures completely identical, including all indices and constraints?

Comment: yes its the same tables but different number of records(dev and stage)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i mean dev db should have less space compared to stage db right if you see the number of records in it